# Scale custom bones

Tags: armature, bones

Does anyone know why custom bone shapes become enormous when applied to a particular bone? How do you get around this?

Answer (score 3):

Check whether you have applied the scaling. The world transformations will be ignored.

So make changes to the custom shape in edit mode or apply location / rotation / scale afterwards.

The shortcut is <kbd>CTRL</kbd>  +  <kbd>A</kbd>  or choose it from the header menu Object -> Apply -> Scale.